# What are the effects of submitting multiple UK visa applications?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

Will a UK spouse visa application automatically cancel any ongoing administrative review, appeal, or pre-action protocol for a previous application?

Answer (score 2):

It will cancel an Administrative Review. [From guidance](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1015181/Administrative_review.pdf)

> If an applicant has made an application for administrative review which is pending,
> the administrative review application ceases to be pending if the applicant makes an
> application for entry clearance, leave to enter or leave to remain. The application for
> administrative review ceases to be pending because the effect of making the fresh
> application is to withdraw the administrative review. The application for
> administrative review is treated as withdrawn under paragraph 34X(4) of the
> Immigration Rules.

You should discuss with your legal representative what the effect of a new application would be on any outstanding legal action you're undertaking (of which a PAP letter would be the first step).